# Displaying elements in Tumblr posts ONLY on the permalink page

Tags: javascript, themes, tumblr

I have a client that would like to put a "back to blog homepage" link on their Tumblr posts. The issue is that using the standard Tumblr framework, that button will appear on permalink posts (where it should be) but also on the index page. Obviously I don't need a link on the homepage pointing TO the homepage. Any ideas on how to specify here? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Link to blog: http://blog.molliestones.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* want it to appear on Posts (ie, not appear on Pages) then you can use this little tweak to @stevether's answer:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}
  <a />
{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

This means if the page being rendered as a date attached to it, which all blog posts do, then it will show. If there is no date attached to it, like all static pages, the link will not show.

Answer (score 0):

```
{block:permalinkpage}
  <a />
{/block:permalinkpage}
```